# How to add download google font in the scss file of react?

Tags: reactjs, sass

```
@font-face {
      font-family: "roboto";
      font-display: swap;
      font-style: normal;
      font-weight: 400;
      src: local("roboto") url(/public/assets/fonts/roboto.woff2);
}
```

[image: Error]
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ijuIE.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/rti1W.png

If will add the downloaded font in the scss file of react so compiler will be show this error. What can I do?

Comment: You are missing a semicolon after `font-family: "roboto" `

Comment: You seemed to have updated your question with the code from the only answer below.  Does that mean that answer was right?  Or not?  If it fixed it, I'd revert your edit and accept the answer, otherwise, if still broken, please tell us what the new error message is?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a semicolon after the font-family declaration:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "roboto"; // <-- Here
  font-display: swap;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local("roboto") url(/public/assets/fonts/roboto.woff2);
}
```

Which will cause a compiler error for SCSS.